# How to convert String to Array list or array in Java

Tags: java

input data likes

```
String input = "[{json}, {json}, ....{json}]"
```

How to convert it to an array or list in Java ?

Comment: Use a JSON parser

Comment: You might want to read [ask] and improve on the quality of your question, e.g. by adding what exactly the result should be. That `{json}` implies you're not after a `List<String>` but need to parse the contained json objects as well. Where do you get that string from in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor quality question, and will probably be closed. I suggest you edit it and explain your goal.

However, it sounds like you're trying to parse JSON. [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) has a long list of JSON parsers for Java at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to convert String to ArrayList,

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("pass the string here"));
```

Refer: https://www.studytonight.com/java-examples/how-to-convert-string-to-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Technically correct -- the best kind of correct!

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jArray != null) { 
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
    listdata.add(jArray.getString(i));
   } 
}
```

If you are trying to covert a JSON object

Comment: To readers: It looks likes the poster is using https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java.